# Python: deleting items from nested list of dictionaries, skipping elements

Tags: python, python-3.6

I am having trouble deleting items from a nested list and seem to have hit a roadblock.

I have a number of test directories, each with a particular test mode. If the parameter KEEP_DIR is set to True, I need the directory. If not, I need to delete the test_mode from my list.

I've tried to create a separate list of test modes that I don't need and then deleting them, without indexing over the original list, but my code is skipping list items once an index has been removed from the dir_dict.

I know list comprehension is probably the best way to go here but every example I have seen is for a 1D list and I've been struggling to understand how to adapt the examples I've seen for my code.

**Here is my nested list:**

```
{
    "TEST_DIRS": [
        {
            "BASE_DIR": "C:\\Path\\to\\files",
            "TEST_MODES": [
                {
                    "DIRS": {
                        "DIR_1": "C:\\Path\\to\\files\\tests\\",
                        "DIR_2": "C:\\Path\to\\files\\logs\\"
                    },
                    "FILES": {
                        "FILE_1": "C:\\Path\\to\\files\\tests\\file1",
                        "FILE_2": "C:\\Path\\to\\files\\tests\\file2"
                    },
                    "KEEP_DIR": true
                },
                {
                    "DIRS": {
                        "DIR_1": "C:\\another\\path\\to\\files\\tests\\",
                        "DIR_2": "C:\\another\\path\\to\\files\\log\\"
                    },
                    "FILES": {
                        "FILE_1": "C:\\another\\path\\to\\files\\tests\\file1",
                        "FILE_2": "C:\\another\\path\\to\\files\\tests\\file2"
                    },
                    "KEEP_DIR": false
                }
            ]
        }
    ]
}
```

**Here is the code I am using:**

```
for i, base_dir in enumerate(dir_dict['TEST_DIRS']):
    for n, test_mode in enumerate(base_dir['TEST_MODES']):
        if not test_mode['KEEP_DIR']:
            fail = (i, n)
            del_list.append(fail)

for item in del_list:
    try:
        del dir_dict['TEST_DIRS'][item[0]]['TEST_MODES'][item[1]]
    except:
        print("Failed to delete:", item)
```

**Output:**

```
Deleting: (0, 0)
Deleting: (0, 1)
Deleting: (0, 2)
Deleting: (0, 3)
Deleting: (0, 4)
Deleting: (0, 5)
Deleting: (0, 6)
Deleting: (0, 7)
Deleting: (0, 8)
Deleting: (0, 9)
Failed to delete: (0, 9)
Deleting: (0, 10)
Failed to delete: (0, 10)
Deleting: (0, 12)
Failed to delete: (0, 12)
Deleting: (0, 13)
Failed to delete: (0, 13)
Deleting: (0, 14)
Failed to delete: (0, 14)
Deleting: (0, 15)
Failed to delete: (0, 15)
Deleting: (0, 16)
Failed to delete: (0, 16)
```

**Traceback:**
When I remove the try, except block - here's the error I get:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
:
:
  File "check_files.py", line 180, in check_dir_dict
    del dir_dict['TEST_DIRS'][item[0]]['TEST_MODES'][item[1]]
IndexError: list assignment index out of range
```

Any help is greatly appreciated.

**Solution:**
As noted by ZZ ll, reversing del_list should removing the indexing issues.
When I reversed the order of del_list, the index are still deleted but they do not shift between each deletion. This looks to be the easiest to implement solution right now:

```
for item in reversed(del_list):
    del dir_dict['SAGE_DIRS'][item[0]]['TEST_MODES'][item[1]]
```

Thanks for all the help :)

Comment: You should display the exception that is being raised.

Comment: Yes, by catching all exceptions, so are making your debug a lot harder, is it a `KeyError`, an `IndexError` or something else?

Comment: What is the expected output?

Comment: There's no error running your code, even after removing the `except:` part.

Comment: I've edited the question to show the traceback log.

Comment: You can run my code @LutzHorn and @ fferri I don't see any errors. Hopefully, someone can point them out, I've just used the correct JSON structure and no errors...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The trouble is that the length of dir_dict['TEST_DIRS'][item[0]]['TEST_MODES'] changes!

```
a = [1,2,3]
del a[0] => a = [2, 3]
del a[1] => a = [2] but your code assumes a = [3]
del a[2] => crash because a is now too small
```

So you have to take into the fact that the index for a specific element is decreased when an element is removed before the specific element or you should remove elements from your list in reversed order:

```
a = [1,2,3]
del a[1] => a = [1, 3]
del a[0] => a = [3]
```

Comment: That's a nice comment but not a solution to the question.

Comment: It seems to address the trouble (which is elements move in the list when an element is removed from it)

Comment: When I cange the line `for item in del_list:` to `for item in reversed(del_list):` the code works as expected :)

Comment: @ZZ Yes, now it does.  First version only described the problem.  It still doesn't say concretely how to change the existing code to achieve the goal.

Answer (score 2):

This here will walk recursively through your data structure and remove all dictionaries which contain a `'KEEP_DIR'` key with associated value `'false'`:

```
def filter_out(orig):
  if isinstance(orig, list):
    return [ filter_out(element)
             for element in orig
             if (not isinstance(element, dict) or
                 element.get('KEEP_DIR', 'true') != 'false') ]
  elif isinstance(orig, dict):
    return { key: filter_out(value)
             for key, value in orig.items() }
  else:
    return orig
```

You might want to adjust to using `False` instead of `'false'` or similar, depending on your actual values.  `false` is not valid in Python.

```
dir_dict = {
    "TEST_DIRS": [
        {
            "BASE_DIR": "C:\\Path\\to\\files",
            "TEST_MODES": [
                {
                    "DIRS": {
                        "DIR_1": "C:\\Path\\to\\files\\tests\\",
                        "DIR_2": "C:\\Path\\to\\files\\logs\\",
                    },
                    "FILES": {
                        "FILE_1": "C:\\Path\\to\\files\\tests\\file1",
                        "FILE_2": "C:\\Path\\to\\files\\tests\\file2",
                    },
                    "KEEP_DIR": 'true',
                },
                {
                    "DIRS": {
                        "DIR_1": "C:\\another\\path\\to\\files\\tests\\",
                        "DIR_2": "C:\\another\\path\\to\\files\\log\\",
                    },
                    "FILES": {
                        "FILE_1": "C:\\another\\path\\to\\files\\tests\\file1",
                        "FILE_2": "C:\\another\\path\\to\\files\\tests\\file2",
                    },
                    "KEEP_DIR": 'false',
                },
           ]
        }
    ]
}
```

And now you can call it like this:

```
import pprint
pprint.pprint(dir_dict)
{'TEST_DIRS': [{'BASE_DIR': 'C:\\Path\\to\\files',
                'TEST_MODES': [{'DIRS': {'DIR_1': 'C:\\Path\\to\\files\\tests\\',
                                         'DIR_2': 'C:\\Path\\to\\files\\logs\\'},
                                'FILES': {'FILE_1': 'C:\\Path\\to\\files\\tests\\file1',
                                          'FILE_2': 'C:\\Path\\to\\files\\tests\\file2'},
                                'KEEP_DIR': 'true'},
                               {'DIRS': {'DIR_1': 'C:\\another\\path\\to\\files\\tests\\',
                                         'DIR_2': 'C:\\another\\path\\to\\files\\log\\'},
                                'FILES': {'FILE_1': 'C:\\another\\path\\to\\files\\tests\\file1',
                                          'FILE_2': 'C:\\another\\path\\to\\files\\tests\\file2'},
                                'KEEP_DIR': 'false'}]}]}
pprint.pprint(filter_out(dir_dict))
{'TEST_DIRS': [{'BASE_DIR': 'C:\\Path\\to\\files',
                'TEST_MODES': [{'DIRS': {'DIR_1': 'C:\\Path\\to\\files\\tests\\',
                                         'DIR_2': 'C:\\Path\\to\\files\\logs\\'},
                                'FILES': {'FILE_1': 'C:\\Path\\to\\files\\tests\\file1',
                                          'FILE_2': 'C:\\Path\\to\\files\\tests\\file2'},
                                'KEEP_DIR': 'true'}]}]}
```

Comment: Can you please explain how I pass my dir_dict to this?

Comment: I added the example call.  You just pass `dir_dict` as input parameter.  The return value will be the new value for this variable, so you might use it like this: `dir_dict = filter_out(dir_dict)`.

Comment: The list is at one stage converted to JSON, which changes `True` -> `true`.
It still evaluates to True though, I'm not sure why but that's another question :)

Comment: @Alfe My solution works with the OPs existing code, I've tried to fix his code instead of writing new.  You're awesome none the less, hopefully you can add some input to my answer, perhaps that is what the OP was looking for.

Answer (score 0):

```
import json
from pprint import pprint

with open('test.json', 'r') as f:
    dir_dict = json.loads(f.read())
# to load from your file or data structure
# do dir_dict = json.load(<varname>) if it's a object if a string use json.loads

del_list = []

for i, base_dir in enumerate(dir_dict['TEST_DIRS']):
    for n, test_mode in enumerate(base_dir['TEST_MODES']):
        if not test_mode['KEEP_DIR']:
            fail = (i, n)
            del_list.append(fail)

for item in del_list:
    try:
        del dir_dict['TEST_DIRS'][item[0]]['TEST_MODES'][item[1]]
    except:
        print("Failed to delete:", item)

pprint(dir_dict)
```

Correct JSON data, test.json:

```
{
    "TEST_DIRS": [
        {
            "BASE_DIR": "C:\\Path\\to\\files",
            "TEST_MODES": [
                {
                    "DIRS": {
                        "DIR_1": "C:\\Path\\to\\files\\tests\\",
                        "DIR_2": "C:\\Path\to\\files\\logs\\"
                    },
                    "FILES": {
                        "FILE_1": "C:\\Path\\to\\files\\tests\\file1",
                        "FILE_2": "C:\\Path\\to\\files\\tests\\file2"
                    },
                    "KEEP_DIR": true
                },
                {
                    "DIRS": {
                        "DIR_1": "C:\\another\\path\\to\\files\\tests\\",
                        "DIR_2": "C:\\another\\path\\to\\files\\log\\"
                    },
                    "FILES": {
                        "FILE_1": "C:\\another\\path\\to\\files\\tests\\file1",
                        "FILE_2": "C:\\another\\path\\to\\files\\tests\\file2"
                    },
                    "KEEP_DIR": false
                }
            ]
        }
    ]
}
```

Everything worked perfectly for me when I used the correct JSON data, didn't throw any errors and output is as expected. Output :*It deleted* `[(0, 1)] (del_list)`

Finally output (as expected):

```
{'TEST_DIRS': [{'BASE_DIR': 'C:\\Path\\to\\files',
                'TEST_MODES': [{'DIRS': {'DIR_1': 'C:\\Path\\to\\files\\tests\\',
                                         'DIR_2': 'C:\\Path\to\\files\\logs\\'},
                                'FILES': {'FILE_1': 'C:\\Path\\to\\files\\tests\\file1',
                                          'FILE_2': 'C:\\Path\\to\\files\\tests\\file2'},
                                'KEEP_DIR': True}]}]}
```

Comment: Hi there,
In my actual code - test_modes has ~18 elements, I only see the fails when I get to index 9.
I've edited my question above to show this.

Are you saying the code is correct but the JSON is wrong?

Comment: Yes, I'm saying you should've just loaded it with JSON and used the correct JSON formatting `\\\` double slash since python recognizes this only.